# How to manage user profile pic updates on AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 for saving user profile pics on a mobile app.

How do I guarantee that request for those pics will not result in a corrupted file if it gets requested while a user updates his image?
Please note that although those files are small it could happen that the connection on the mobile app drops, resulting in a stalled upload (maybe even for hours).

My first idea was to upload the new file under a temporary name and upon completion delete the original file and rename the uploaded file.
I couldn't find any commands for that in the iOS SDK though.

Another approach would be to just increment a number with the filename and always point to the new file in the database upon completion. But this results in a big headache and unneeded complexity for cleanup since I am using a denormalized nosql database.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're worrying about a non-problem.

S3 uploads are atomic.  When you overwrite an object on S3, there is zero chance of corrupting a download of the previous object.  The object isn't technically "overwritten" -- it is replaced -- a fine distinction, but with a difference -- nothing at all happens to the old object until the replacement upload has finished successfully.

(In fact, it's possible though unlikely that the previous object will still be returned for a short time after the new upload has completed, because of S3's eventual consistency model on overwrites).

Additionally, if you send the `Content-MD5` header with an S3 upload, then a failure in the upload process (stall, lost connection, corruption, etc.) will absolutely not allow the replacement object to be stored at all -- S3 will abort the operation and the prior version will remain intact unless the uploaded object can be validated against the `Content-MD5` specified.  (The SDK should be doing this for you.)

Note that this holds true whether or not object versioning is enabled on the bucket.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! :)